# Problem adding a .asmx file to a custom subfolder within a DNN site in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to add some web service (.asmx) functionality to a DNN 5.6 website.

I've added this using some code behind (which I've placed in /App_Code) and a .asmx file which I'd like to place in a new roor folder - /Services/MyService.asmx

This functionality works fine locally under cassini.

However, when I deploy to IIS7, then I get a 404 for the .asmx file.

Here are some of the experiments I've done:

- If I move the file to the /DesktopModules/MyService.asmx then everything works fine - I can see the .asmx file and I can call the service functions without any problems.
- If I turn directory browsing on inside IIS7, then I can browse to /Services and see the .asmx file - but when I click through to that .asmx file then I get 404.
- If I add a gif file to /Services then I can see this without any problems

Has anyone got any suggestions about what might be causing this? I'm wondering if it's the friendly name code within DNN somehow picking this .asmx file up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the friendly URL provider isn't going to allow that in DNN 5.6.  In 5.6.2, there will be a setting to let you exclude URLs from the friendly URL provider, to let you get around this issue.

Comment: Thanks - is this a change in a recent DNN version? Version numbers we're running are 5.6.1.238. Also, I'm not sure why this seems to work on local Cassini but not on the server? Isn't the friendly URL code independent of the web server?

Comment: Cassini might automatically map to the file if it exists?  I'm not sure what would be different there.  Yes, this change happened in DNN 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.